# Is there any way to remove constexpr

Tags: c++, constexpr

I got a pointer of constexpr const class*.

Is there any way to remove constexpr, so I can access a variable editing member of class. Thank you

(Yes, I ask a similar question removing const flag, butI think breaking down to the individual facts, combined with a general question, helps subsequent users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to remove `constexpr` from a variable. `constexpr` variables are treated as literal types which are fundamentally constant. You can copy the variable and modify that instead.

```
constexpr const T* var = ...
const T* copy = var;
```

Note that the `constexpr` here applies to the pointer, not the data pointed at.